# lit element query() returning null

Tags: lit-element, lit

I'm using the query() to reference a lit element. For example

```
@query('#first')
_first;
```

However, that lit element hasn't been rendered to the dom yet and the #first returns null. When I do this._first = null. What can I do to make sure that first is not null? How can I wait for the lit element to be rendered to the dom?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, `@query` will return `null` before the initial update has completed because the element hasn't rendered yet.

One possible option is to use the [`@queryAsync`](https://lit.dev/docs/components/shadow-dom/#query-async) decorator. Instead of returning your element or `null` synchronously, it returns a promise that resolves to the queried node after any pending render is completed.

Another option is to await [`this.updateComplete`](https://lit.dev/docs/components/lifecycle/#updatecomplete) which also lets you wait for any pending updates to complete before querying the rendered DOM. E.g. from the linked `updateComplete` docs: "When writing tests you can await the updateComplete Promise before making assertions about the component’s DOM."

```js
await this.updateComplete; // Wait for pending update to render #first
this._first // Result of querying for #first on rendered DOM in this.renderRoot.
```